# Android getInstalledPackages

Tags: android

I am creating an android app which has the list of all the apps which user can access from its android phone menu.
Here is my code which is working successfully..

```
List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

          // the package manager contains the information about all installed apps
          PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

          List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); //PackageManager.GET_META_DATA 

          for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
             PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
             ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo;
             // skip system apps if they shall not be included
             if ((!includeSysApps) && ((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)) {
                continue;
             }
             App app = new App();
             app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
             app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
             app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
             app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
             CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(packageManager);
             app.setDescription(description != null ? description.toString() : "");
             apps.add(app);
          }
```

Now this gives me a big list and i can classify its items in 3 ways :

1st (Apps like): Speed Moto, Subway Surf, Chrome (Which i installed)

2nd (Apps like):Camera, Email, Messaging (Installed by Default)

3rd (.... Like):PageBuddyNotiSvc, Dialer Storage etc (Some Packages)

Now i want to filter the 3rd type of Apps and want to keep only 1st and 2nd type..
How can i achieve this list..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information about each application using the following code

```
ApplicationInfo app = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
//And then check the  dir

if (app.sourceDir.startsWith("/data/app/")) {
    //Non-system app
}
else {
    //System app
}
```

Comment: There is no way to catergorize an app as game or not. all you could achieve is either it is default app or 2rd party. Or you could categorize based on the permissions of the app.